# Knapsack cover inequalities for a particular covering problem

Tags: combinatorics, linear-programming, integer-programming

The Knapsack cover inequalities for a constraint $ A_i  x \geq  b$ where $x_{j}\in\{0,1\}$  are:
$$\sum_{ j \notin S}  \tilde{ a}_j x_j \geq b_i −\sum_{ j \in S }  1  $$ 
with  $\tilde{ a}_j  = \min \{a_j , b_i − \sum_{ j \in S }  1  \}$.
Given a covering polyhedron $P$ given by $ \{ x \ : \ Ax \geq b,  \ \ \  0 \leq x \leq 1 \} $    it is known that the integrality gap of $P'$ (given by constraints in $P$ and additional knapsack cover inequalites) and the integral hull of $P$ [is at most 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.08951.pdf).

Suppose our covering polyhedron is given, that $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ with $n$ even and large, and that the rows of A are all vectors with $n/2$ ones.  How would one go about finding a knapsack cover inequality that cuts the point 0.1 * $\mathbb{1}$ (with $\mathbb{1}$ the all ones vector)? I understand one can do this with iterative Chvátal cuts, but I'm wondering how one would use knapsack cover inequalities to cut such a point.